# Do #ifdef, #ifndef and #undef work with function-like macros?

Tags: c, macros, conditional-compilation

There are two types of macros - [function-like macros](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html#SEC12) and [object-like macros](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html#SEC11). I can perform various checks/operations on object-like macros:

```
#ifdef _SOME_OBJECT_LIKE_MACRO    // check if some object-like macro is defined
#undef _SOME_OBJECT_LIKE_MACRO    // undefine some object-like macro
#endif

#define _SOME_OBJECT_LIKE_MACRO 0xff
```

Do `#ifdef`, `#ifndef` and `#undef` work with function-like macros? For example:

```
#ifdef _SOME_FUNCTION_LIKE_MACRO()  // check if some function-like macro is defined
#undef _SOME_FUNCTION_LIKE_MACRO()  // undefine some function-like macro
#endif

#define _SOME_FUNCTION_LIKE_MACRO() printf("This is such a useful macro!!!\n");
```

Does that work? If not, how can I...

- check the existence of
- check the *non*existence of
- undefine

...a function-like macro?

Comment: You should note that names starting with an underscore and either an upper-case letter or another underscore are absolutely reserved for the implementation to use — you should not create such names in your own code (though you might use system-provided names like that).  In fact, you're probably best off avoiding leading underscores altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, and `#undef` work with function-like macros but you only need to use the bare macro name. There is no need for the parentheses:

```
#ifdef _SOME_FUNCTION_LIKE_MACRO
#undef _SOME_FUNCTION_LIKE_MACRO
#endif
```

Also see http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html#SEC19.

Comment: Note that there's no need to test before `#undef`; the standard has always stipulated that `#undef UNDEFINED_MACRO` is not an error.